# git p4 sync changelist interval

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

My goal is to sync the repository from p4 using an interval of changelists so that the first changelist version of the repository would be considered as an initial commit.
So I used the following command:

```
git p4 clone //path-to-project@cl1,cl2
```

where `cl1` and `cl2` are numbers of mentioned changelists.

And when it finished, the files, that were created before the `cl1` were not in the `HEAD`.

The problem, as I see it, is that before syncing changes in the given range, p4 task does not sync to `cl1` version of the repo, and applies commits to the empty repository.

Is it a bug or my misunderstanding of how git p4 should work? And how should I do this correctly?

UPD: The reason I need changelist interval is that there is a problem with the p4 database and I can't checkout changelists before one point in the past. And I would like to migrate to git with all accessible history.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, apart from the special import just the head revision default option, the @cl1,cl2 options only import the changelists, not the state of the repository at those changelists.

I think you'll have to do @all to get the complete history. Or alter git-p4 to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to sync the repository from p4 using an interval of changelists so that the first changelist version of the repository would be considered as an initial commit.

When you first clone your repository with `git-p4`, the change you clone from is already treated as the initial commit.  That is,

```
git p4 clone //path-to-project@cl1
```

by itself should do what you want.

It's unclear why you're trying to use a revision range (`cl1,cl2`) since your problem description doesn't mention `cl2` at all.

Comment: I also need all the history since `cl1` to `cl2` in my repository, I thought it is obvious.

There is a problem with the p4 database and I can't checkout changelists before one point in the past. And I would like to migrate to git with all accessible history.

Comment: @goto1134 You are still not being clear.  Do you mean that you can't check out changes prior to `cl1` but that syncing to `cl1` from a Perforce client works?  If so, then the instructions I gave should still work.  You can clone the git repository from `cl1` as a single commit and afterward do `git p4 sync @cl2`. (It's still not at all obvious why you care about `cl2` and can't just sync to the Perforce `HEAD`.)

Comment: Yes, your assumption is right, I can check out `cl1` and can't check out `cl1 - 1`.

And yes, I need to sync to `HEAD`, but I tried to describe a general case, in which it could be just another changelist.

Comment: @goto1134 Ok, so does my answer work for you or not, and if not, why not?

Comment: It does not work when I do `git p4 sync`, because git can't apply commits to the current version

Comment: @goto1134 Sorry, I was confused.  After doing `git p4 clone //path-to-project@cl1`, you should just do `git p4 rebase`.  You cannot specify `cl2`, but it's still not clear why it really matters.  After it pulls in all of the Perforce changes after cl1, you're free to throw away commits after cl2 as you wish.